# How to pass json object with api in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, coinbase-api

https://api.coinbase.com/v1/transactions/send_money 

 pass bellow Parameter with this api.

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "to": "user1@example.com",
    "amount": "1.234",
    "notes": "Sample transaction for you"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this ans ..

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic setObject:@"user1@example.com" forKey:@"to"];
        [dic setObject:@"1.234" forKey:@"amount"];
        [dic setObject:@"sending money" forKey:@"notes"];

NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dic,@"transaction", nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example using the [Coinbase iOS SDK](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ios-sdk):

```
NSDictionary *transactionDict = @{
    @"to": @"user1@example.com",
    @"amount": @"1.234",
    @"notes": @"sending money" };
NSDictionary *params = @{ @"transaction": transactionDict };

[apiClient doPost:@"transactions/send_money" params:transactionDict completion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Could not send money: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", [result objectForKey:@"transaction"]);
    }
}];
```